# How do you concatenate symbols in mxnet

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, deep-learning, mxnet

I have 2 symbols in MXNet and would like to concatenate them. How can i do this:

eg: `a = [100,200]`, `b = [300,400]`, Id like to get

`c = [100,200,300,400]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by using the "[Concat](http://mxnet.io/api/python/symbol.html#mxnet.symbol.concat)" method.

```
a = mx.sym.Variable('a')
b = mx.sym.Variable('b')
c = mx.sym.Concat(a,b,dim=0)
```

To verify this, you can execute your symbol using an executor to check:

```
e = c.bind(mx.cpu(), {'a': mx.nd.array([100,200]), 'b':mx.nd.array([300,400])})
y = e.forward()
y[0].asnumpy()
```

You will get the output:

```
array([ 100.,  200.,  300.,  400.], dtype=float32)
```